# Variável em requisição Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, variáveis, session

Código para receber o `numeroCartao` do usuário via `$_Session` e mostrar todas as informações sobre ele. E a partir daqui eu posso excluir este usuário via AJAX.

Neste trecho do código posso ver o array contendo todos os dados do usuário, porém no arquivo `processaDadosExcluir.php` não encontro o mesmo array, o que gera um erro de `undefined variable`. E isso impede de executar o SQL.

Como posso passar uma variável para o arquivo `processaDadosExcluir.php` de forma que seja reconhecida neste arquivo a fim de ser executada a query?

```
<?php ?>
<script type="text/javascript">    
    $('#excluirdep').submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var valores = $('#excluirdep').serialize();

        console.log(valores);

         $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'ajax/processaDadosExcluir.php',
            data: valores,
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    $("#excluirDependente").html(data);
            }
        });
    });
</script>    
<?php

echo "Excluir pernamente o usuario: <br> Nome: ".$linha['NomeBeneficiario']."<br>
      Numero da Carteira: ".$_SESSION ['NumeroCartao']."<br>";   

 /*variaveis de sessao*/
$numeroCartao  = $_SESSION['NumeroCartao'];

//conexao
$con    =   mysql_connect("10.6.0.27","root","prtdb") or die("Erro na conexao!");
$db     =   mysql_select_db("teste001", $con) or die("Erro na selecao do banco");

//query
$sql = "DELETE FROM PlanAssiste WHERE NumeroCartao =".$numeroCartao;

//executar a query
$query = mysql_query($sql,$con) or die("Erro na Query-3: ".mysql_error());

//resposta
if ($query == NULL){    
    $return['msg'] = " <a href='#' class='close'>Fechar [X]</a> <br> <b> Nullo! </B>";
    echo $return['msg'];
}
else{
    $return['msg'] = "<div id='excluir' class='alter'>  
                         <p><label> Excluido com Sucesso! </label> </p>
                         <p><a href='javascript:history.back(0)' >Fechar [X]</a> </p> 
                     </div>

                    <style>
                        .alter{
                            width: 240px;
                            height: 200px;
                            color: red;
                        }
                    </style> ";
    echo $return['msg'];
}
?>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Como se chama o ficheiro que colocou em cima?

Comment: Depois de ter editado, estou com a impressão que você colocou o código de seus dois arquivos sem nenhuma identificação ou separação ao fazer o copy/paste  (`arquivo1.php -> código` **+** `arquivo2.php -> código`).

Comment: Exatamente, são dois arquivos...usuario.php e processaDadosExcluir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solucionado

Na página em que faço a requisição ajax, criei uma um input tipo hidden com nome numeroCartao dentro do formulário o qual uso para coletar os dados para ser enviado via ajax para processaDadosExcluir.php

```
 <FORM id="excluirdep" name="excluirdep">
        <input name = "numeroCartao" id='numeroCartao' type="hidden" value='<?php echo $numeroCartao; ?>'  />
```

Poes bem, no trecho do código javascript alterei uma linha:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$('#excluirdep').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var valores = $('#excluirdep').serialize();
    //variavel criada para receber o valor do imput hidden com o dado que quero
    var numerocartao = $("input[name=numeroCartao]").val();
    console.log(valores);

     $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'ajax/processaDadosExcluir.php',
        data: {primeiro:valores,segundo:numerocartao},
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                $("#excluirDependente").html(data);
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(xhr.status);
            alert(thrownError);
        }
    });
});
```

Na parte php, apenas coloquei uma linha:

```
$numeroCartao = $_POST["segundo"];
```

Aqui recuperou o valor do id para realizar a busca sql e apagar os dados do usuário!